# Create an alert on any view controller from a method

Tags: iphone, facebook, cocoa-touch, uialertview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Create an alert on any view controller after Facebook request:didFailWithError:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11235155/create-an-alert-on-any-view-controller-after-facebook-requestdidfailwitherror)

I have a method that gets called if a video upload to Facebook has failed. If that method is called then I would like for a UIAlertView to appear in any view controller that a user happens to be on at the time the upload fails.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UIAlertView` creates it's own `UIWindow` above your application's main window and makes it key and visible. Any UIAlertView created by your application should be visible on any view controller in your application's main window.

Answer (score 1):

```
-(void)yourMethod{

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] init];
        [alert setTitle:@"Failed to upload video"];
        [alert setMessage:@"bla bla bla"];
        [alert setDelegate:self];
        [alert addButtonWithTitle:@"Ok"];
        [alert show];
}
```

then you can have this method to control what happens after the user clicks a button in your alert:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    if (buttonIndex == 0 ){
        //do something
    }else if (buttonIndex == 1){
        //if you add more buttons
        //do something
    }
}
```

if you have more alert-views, you could add a tag `[alert setTag:(int)]` to identify them in the `-(void)alertView` method with `[alertView getTag]`